# Calling GDAL (programs) from Python

Tags: python, gdal, editing

Could someone navigate me for using/calling GDAL stand-alone [programs](https://gdal.org/programs/index.html) from Python? I have GDAL 2.3.2 and Python 3.7. 
When I call gdal from python I can access to a limited number of functions including gdal.Warp() and gdal.Translate(). I can not however access 'gdal_edit' which I am currently interested to use. In the Git page of this function I did not find any information regarding access to this function either!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

gdal_edit is itself a python script - you should be able to find it located within your GDAL installation.

To access it from Python, you can use the subprocess library to call the script. e.g.

```
import subprocess as sp

#locate your gdal_edit script
gdaledit = r"C:\Program Files\GDAL\gdal_edit.py"

#input data 
srcdata = 'abc.tif'

cmd = [gdaledit, '-a_srs', 'EPSG:4326', '-tr', '150', srcdata]
sp.check_call(cmd, shell=True)
```

You use the `shell=True` argument so that Python can effectively run the script from the command line. Without it, you will get an error.

Comment: Yes, that's what i usually do, too. But as i read the question, i thought, that you also can try to Import those Scripts to get more control over the process.

Comment: Yes Andreas, after GDAL 2.0.0 you can directly call some functions (without the need of using subprocess) but not all of them (including gdal_edit, gdal_merge, etc.)